# linux command for jmx as csv Input and Output file

Tags: linux, csv, input, jmeter, output

If we want to give CSV file input and CSV/xl file as output in command line , what should be the syntax . Correct me if iam wrong with below syntax ?

syntax : jmeter -n -t /users/test.jmx -l /users/test.csv -l log.csv

Comment: How to read data from CSV File and run jmx file in linux

If my jmx file is login.jmx
my input file is   users.csv

what should be the syntax or command in linux

Answer (score 2):

You don't need this bit: `-l log.csv`

- `-n` - instructs JMeter to run in [command-line non-GUI mode](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/dear-abby-blazemeter-how-do-i-run-jmeter-non-gui-mode/)
- `-t` - location of the [.jmx test script](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/JMETER/JmxTestPlan)
- `-l` - location of the [.jtl results file](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/JMETER/JtlFiles), by default it is in CSV format and stores metrics according to the [Results File Configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#results_file_config)

More information: [Full list of command-line options](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options)

Comment: Have you even tried to open the [Full list of command-line options](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options)? I'm asking because there is `-j, --jmeterlogfile <argument>  jmeter run log file (jmeter.log)` entry which should be informative enough. If you need more information on amending log setup - check out [How to Configure JMeter Logging](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-configure-jmeter-logging) article

Comment: ok. the (short) option names are  ambiguous enough to cause misunderstandings. but clear now. i'd rather use the long ones.